# Printing using on_start and self in Locust

Tags: python, locust

Having this code:

```
class MyUser(HttpUser):
host="http://localhost"

def on_start(self):
    self.data = data.sample().to_dict()
    self.ts_value_random = random.randrange(10000)


@task
def send_request(self):
    print("Sending request with data: ", self.data)
    print("Random_value: ", self.ts_value_random)
    self.client.get("/hello", data=self.data)
```

Why is only "Sending request with data:" printed to console when running i.e. 5 Virtual Users?

Comment: just a thought, but is data a bunch of blank lines? Or does the task decorator eat the rest?

Comment: data = pd.read_csv('C:\\path\\TS_ID.csv').head(30), where TS_ID.csv is a large file

Comment: Your code is missing some indentation. Did it get messed up when pasting it to SO or is that the way you have it in your actual locustfile?

Comment: is data.sample().to_dict() *really* slow?

Comment: The Locust file is formatted correctly. should this data.sample().to_dict() be slow for some reason?